# Why is o.pet null even though I set it to be a value?

Tags: java, exception, null, project, computer-science

I'm doing an apcs project on a RescueCenter where people can adopt animals and more. The problem I'm encountering is that in my UI, when I try to list the pets of the selected owner, an exception comes up saying that it can't read o.pet since it's null. I was wondering why it's null even though I set a's  owner to be `this` in the Owner adopt function and called it in the RescueCenter adopt function?

`Owner class`

```
void adopt(Animal a) {
            pet = a;
            a.owner = this;
    }
```

`RescueCenter class:`

```
public boolean adopt(String customerName, String animalName) {
        Owner o = new Owner(customerName, age);
        Animal d = new Dog(animalType, animalName, animalBreed, animalAge);
        if (!o.isQualified() || !d.isQualified()) {
            o.qualify();
            d.qualify();
        }
        if (o.isQualified() && d.isQualified()) {
            o.adopt(d);
            d = o.pet;
            adoptableAnimalList.remove(d);
            return true;
        }
            return false;
    }

public String getPet(String currCustomerName) {
        Owner o = new Owner(currCustomerName, age);
        return o.pet.name;
    }
```

Comment: Did you check that `o.adopt(d);` actually happens? Could the bug be in `isQualified`, causing qualified pets or owners not to be recognized? Or in `qualify`, failing to qualify them? Also, *where does `RescueCenter#adopt` actually get called?*

Answer (score 1):

You create a `new Owner` but never call `adopt` on it. (For that matter, you also create and then discard objects in `adopt`.) What you are *probably* looking for is something like a `Map<String, Owner>` where you can store and retrieve `Owner` objects.